# Drag and drop sprites in libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I have an app, that uses Sprites in specific points. I would like to move these Sprites by finger to another coordinates.
I draw sprites with use of code above.

```
                vertexSprite[j].setPosition(p.x - vertexSprite[j].getWidth()/2, p.y - vertexSprite[j].getHeight()/2);
                vertexSprite[j].draw(batch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement interface `InputProcessor`and use `touchDragged()` method to get event and update your sprite coordinates when dragging happens.

Comment: Can I also redraw/refresh lines between sprites?

Comment: You have that loop when you do drawing. This method is only for updating variables and stuff. You do all the drawing from the same place.

Comment: It seems not that easy, beacuse it should be implemented in render for continuous refresh.